# How to make dynamically added content clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding dynamic content to a php page using jQuery. I don't have a problem adding the content I just can't seem to find a way to make the new content respond to a click event.

For example (I'm using a div here but could be a button or other type).

```
$("#oldstuff").after('<div id="newstuff">Some content that should respond to click event</div>');
```

Edit:
I am currently using jquery 1.9.1, I was using 1.6.2 but I am checking out magnific-popup which required a newer jquery version.

I didn't post my failed attempts (

```
 $("#newstuff").click(function() {...
 $("#newstuff").live('click', function() {...
 binding the click event, etc.
```

because I assumed that I am missing something fundamental that a more seasoned jQuery user would spot without the noise of broken code.

Comment: Where is your click event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can't seem to find a way to make the new content respond to a click event.

You have to do [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#oldstuff").on("click", '#newstuff',function(){
alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

Comment: This works - could someone explain why this was voted down?

Comment: It's the **most** annoying thing on SO when someone downvotes without reason.

Comment: This works great and requires the least amount of changes to my existing code - thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can attach a click event *before* inserting the element into the DOM:

```
$('<div id="newstuff">...</div>').click(function(){ 
  //do something 
}).insertAfter('#oldstuff');
```

Comment: Not familiar with doing it this way, will check this out...

Comment: This shows promise and I will explore it more in the future. Currently  I separate my content insertion/modification code from my event handling code and as such there was another response that was a better solution to what I was looking for. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to attach the event to the parent element.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="thediv">Hello</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function addDiv() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'thediv';
    document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(div);
}

$('#parent').on('click', '.thediv', function() {
    // ...
});
```

See if this technique works.

Comment: That technique is event delegation ..Yes this works here

Answer (score -1):

It is probably you are binding event before attaching DOM and also in latest version of jquery library live method is deprecated so try to bind click even after attaching DOM or you can use  following code...

first add DOM.

```
    $("#oldstuff").after('<div id="newstuff">Some content that should respond to click event</div>');
```

and then bind event.

```
    $('#newstuff').on('click',function(){alert('do your stuff!')});
```

Or

```
    $('#newstuff').click(function(){alert('do your stuff!')});
```

Comment: Any reason your entire post is code?

Comment: Neither of these work on dynamic content. If I understand correctly what the other comments are saying it's because '#newstuff' was not part of original content loaded in the DOM but added afterward.

Comment: you can bind event on existing DOM as your DOM (<div id="newstuff">Some content that should respond to click event</div>) loaded later so you should bind event after loading DOM then it will work

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$("#yourElementId").live("click",function(){
  alert( $(this).text() );
 });
```

As `.click` is not working after loading dom or dynamically created element

Comment: Can anyone Explain why downvote that post. Wheather we all know after dom loading `.click` is not working as `.click` is attach before dom loading. So jquery have new method `.live` or `.on` but `.live` is depriciated newer version. And same is working in my case.

Comment: Because `.on()`'s syntax differs from `.live()` where in the objet selected is the static element, the first argument is the event, the 2nd is the dynamic element, and the third is the callbakc.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy for your kind attention, i have found syntax form Jquery official site `http://api.jquery.com/on/` now can you also explain why ?

Comment: @All Downvoter i have made sample on Fiddle`http://fiddle.jshell.net/dubeynee/RmBpZ/1/` where i have add `p` dynamically and attach `click` event by `.on` now tell whats wrong with you.

Comment: Because in your jsFiddle, you do the append before the click, therefroe it's available in the DOM. [Place it after the click](http://fiddle.jshell.net/qM6cE/). And once you've done that, [Check it out in proper fashion](http://fiddle.jshell.net/w5BdZ/)

Comment: In your example you are binding the handler *after* you added the new DOM element. Of course that works. But your explanation is wrong. It seems you suggested to use event delegation, but you are not showing how. The code you posted is exactly the same as using .click. Please read the complete .on documentation, there is a section which explains this.

Comment: Can you all tell me wheather my code is working or not.I think it's working and requested to all please leave comment before downvote so that people can improve himself.

Comment: @NeerajDubey: _Read_ the comments above. There is plenty of explanation about why your answer is wrong and/or incomplete.